# SSIS split XML text

Tags: xml, ssis, split, textnode

I'm wondering if there is someone who can help me to acheive the following. I have a XML file with a text value containing for every week a value. I would like to put every week into a database as a seperate row.

I know how to put XML files into a database using SSIS but i need some help how to start splitting the text value.

Many thanks!

```
<DATA>
<TIME-SERIES last-update-time="507340800" name="yearly" sample-interval="604800" observations="52" parent="http:client-volume">143 161 175 112 176 191 188 163 268 303 261 270 264 182 318 307 339 310 328 338 407 485 3330 274 168 191 179 258 183 256 258 238 2625 235 305 274 255 273 367 188 318 230 315 278 192 222 1268 129 150 350 3278 4757 </TIME-SERIES>
</DATA>
```

prefered output

```
date      | name   | interval | observation | parent             | value
507340800 | yearly | 604800   | 52          | http:client-volume | 143
507340800 | yearly | 604800   | 52          | http:client-volume | 161
507340800 | yearly | 604800   | 52          | http:client-volume | 175
```

Comment: What should the output of the above look like?

Comment: @billinkc see original post, just edited

Answer (score 0):

How about writing a little xsl snippet for that?
Here's one I came up with, run with: `xsltproc MY_XSL_FILE YOUR_XML_FILE`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:s="http://exslt.org/strings"
  version="1.0">

  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:template match="text()"/>

  <xsl:template match="TIME-SERIES">
    <xsl:variable name="last-update-time" select="@last-update-time"/>
    <xsl:variable name="name" select="@name"/>
    <xsl:variable name="sample-interval" select="@sample-interval"/>
    <xsl:variable name="observations" select="@observations"/>
    <xsl:variable name="parent" select="@parent"/>

    <!-- heading -->
    <xsl:text>date      | name   | interval | observation | parent             | value&#0010;</xsl:text>

    <xsl:for-each select="s:tokenize(text(), ' ')">
      <xsl:value-of select="$last-update-time"/>
      <xsl:text> | </xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="$name"/>
      <xsl:text> | </xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="$sample-interval"/>
      <xsl:text>  | </xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="$observations"/>
      <xsl:text>           | </xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="$parent"/>
      <xsl:text> | </xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      <xsl:text>&#0010;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```